# ResourceBundle doesn't find resource files

Tags: java, internationalization

I have this simple code:

```
public class Main{
    private static Locale currentLocale = new Locale("pl", "PL");
    private static ResourceBundle text; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        text = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resBundle", currentLocale);
    }
}
```

and in the src directory I also have 2 resource files named `resBundle.properties` and `resBundle_pl_PL.properties` that contain translations of my program. However, this code generates an exception in the main method. It says that it doesn't find the resource file, even though it is there. In the beginning I had the files in the main directory but after reading up I moved them to src where they're supposed to be.

Any idea what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Where is the resource stored (relative to the `src` directory)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer They are inside the src directory, as stated above
EDIT: Actually, no, sorry, I just noticed they were stored inside the package, instead of the src directory, that fixed the problem. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: But where?  Are they in the default package (`/`)?  Are the in a subdirectory/package? Where does `main` reside in relationship to the resource bundle?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime classpath is used by the classloader when it looks for the properties files.

So you will need to consider where the properties files are in relation to the compiled .class file rather than the source .java file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for posting this, I thought i tried all the things, and I just noticed that the resource files were placed inside the package instead of the src folder. It was actually quite hard to spot in eclipse. That fixed the problem.